# Combine Row Values to "Others"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a maybe really tricky question. I have a table with costs, very simple:

```
Cost name, cost value
```

And I want to output the `TOP 10` costs values with the name, which is no problem, BUT: as 11th row, I want to output all others sum as "Others" marked ... Is that possible with a SQL query?

I hope you understand my question and I'm very thankful for all helpful answers.

Best regards,

Tobias

UPDATE:

[image]

<< Data Example >>

Comment: Can you provide a sample i.e data and output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
;with T as(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by value desc) RNum
    from YourTable
)
select value, name from T 
where RNum<=10

union all

select sum(value), 'Others'
from T
where RNum>10
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it out, unfortunatly, the real tables are much complicated, so I need some time, but I will return when I got it!

Comment: I tried your example and it worked very well! And by sorting it via RowNumber you can be sure, that your 'Others' column will be at the end!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
select * from (select top (10) name, value from costs order by value) s1
UNION (
   select 'other', sum(value) from costs 
   where name not in (select top 10 Name from costs order by value)
)
```

This assumes Name is a PK on costs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it out, unfortunatly, the real tables are much complicated, so I need some time, but I will return when I got it!

Comment: Thank you very much, this example would be very tricky to use for my case, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
;with CTE as(SELECT Name ,
value ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RowNumber FROM #Temp )

select Name,value 
from cte
Where RowNumber<11
union
select 'Other',Sum(value)
from cte
Where RowNumber>=11
```

Sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ddcdf/1)